# beginner rerrange data in a csv file

Tags: r, csv

This is really basic, but I am getting stuck with overly complicated code. I have a CSV file with a column of tests, a column of marks, and a column of students. I would like to reformat the data such that I have rows of student marks and columns of the tests.

I created a separate csv that contains the students (as number codes) called "students.csv" as this was easier for now.

I have 52 students and 50 tests.

I can get the following to work with a single student:

```
matricNumbers <- read.csv("students.csv")
students <- as.vector(as.matrix(matricNumbers))
students
data <- read.csv("marks.csv")
studentSubset <- data[data[2] == 1150761,] 
marksSubset <- as.vector(as.matrix(studentSubset[5]))
ll <- list()
ll<-c(list(marksSubset), ll)
dd<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=50,ncol=50))
for(i in 1:length(ll)){
  dd[i,] <- ll[[i]]

}
dd
```

but I can't seem to get this to work with a `for` loop to go through every student.

```
getMarks <-function(studentNumFile,markFile){

matricNumbers <- read.csv(studentNumFile)
students <- as.vector(as.matrix(matricNumbers))


data <- read.csv(markFile)

for (i in seq_along(students)){
    studentSubset <- data[data[2] == i,] 
    marksSubset <- as.vector(as.matrix(studentSubset[5]))
    ll <- list()
    ll<-c(list(marksSubset), ll)
    dd<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=52,ncol=50))
    for(i in 1:length(ll)){
        dd[i,] <- ll[[i]]
    }
}
return(dd)
}

getMarks("students.csv","marks.csv")
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, , value = logical(0)) : replacement has 0 items, need 50
```

I am sure this is due to the nested `for` loop but I can't figure out how to do this otherwise.

Comment: What is the value of `i` when it stops? That should be the one causing the error. Can you show that subset? Also, have you tried replacing the `i` in the nested loop with `j` for clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `reshape` package to achieve what you want if I understand the problem correctly. As you don't provide sample data it is hard to test. I advise you paste the output of `dput( head( matricNumbers ) )` into a code block above for this purpose.

However, you should be able to follow this simple example that I use with some dummy data. I think you may only need one line, and you can forget all the complicated loop stuff!

```
# These lines make some dummy data, similar to you matricNumbers (hopefully)
test = sort(sample(c("Biology","Maths","Chemistry") , 10 , repl = TRUE ))
students = unlist( sapply(table(test), function(x) { sample( letters[1:x] , x ) } ) )
names(students) <- NULL
scores <- data.frame( test , mark = sample( 40:100 , 10 , repl = TRUE ) , students )
scores
        test mark students
1    Biology   50        c
2    Biology   93        a
3    Biology   83        b
4    Biology   83        d
5  Chemistry   71        b
6  Chemistry   54        c
7  Chemistry   54        a
8      Maths   97        c
9      Maths   93        b
10     Maths   72        a



# Then use reshape to cast your data into the format you require
# I use 'mean' as the aggregation function. If you have one score for each student/test, then mean will just return the score
# If you do not have a score for a particular student in that test then it will return NaN
require( reshape )
bystudent <- cast( scores , students ~ test , value = "mark" , mean )
bystudent
  students Biology Chemistry Maths
1        a      93        54    72
2        b      83        71    93
3        c      50        54    97
4        d      83       NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Perfect, this was sooooo much easier! Thank You!